# Is it possible to make an Array of Rectangles in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a very simple grid in which a user can move through. Through my research i have concluded that the best way to achieve this would be using a two-dimensional array to represent the grid. However i am unsure of how to draw this array to a Jframe or Jpanel if i were to make an array of rectangles.

[image: Example]

Many Stackoverflow questions seem to ask simmilar queries but unforunately i have found non that entirely explains how to draw a simple grid of rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make arrays out of everything. Notice how the way to implement an array is

```
*datatype* [] *arrayname* = new *datatype* [*lengthOfArray*];
```

Lets say the name of the class that contains the rectangles is RECTANGLE. So if you want an Array, that contains, lets say, 5 rectangles, it would look somewhat like that:

```
RECTANGLE [] rectangelArray = new RECTANGLE [5];
```

If you want to take that to a 2 dimensional Level, just add another bracket:

```
RECTANGLE [][] rectangelMatrix = new RECTANGLE [4][5];
```

Assuming that by "drawing to the JPanel" you mean that you want to put the rectangles onto the screen, you would then have a for-loop in a for-loop, that would for example call each rectangle to draw itself:

```
for(int i = 0; i<rectangleMatrix.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<rectangleMatrix[i].length; j++){
        rectangleMatrix[i][j].draw();
    }
}
```

`rectangleMatrix.draw()` calls a method that will draw the rectangle based on its coordinates and size. you could also in a similar fashion call a method that will read the information of each rectangle and then draw it based on that information. This will help you seperate between information and drawing purposes in your classes, which is always a good thing to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i<rectangleMatrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<rectangleMatrix[i].length; j++){
            drawRectangle(rectangleMatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

drawRectangle(RECTANGLE toDraw) is in the same class that you have the method with the for-loop in.

Comment: Wow that's a really helpful explanation, Been battling for quite some time!

Comment: Do you think using something like the [Rectangle2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) class might be more beneficial than actually creating my own Rectangle class

Answer (score 1):

In your parent component of grid set layout like 
`gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(ix, iy));`

where ix and iy is dimension size
you also need array of cells `private Cell[][] cells;` in this case cell is simply

```
public class Cell extends JPanel{
     //some game specific code, fields, constructors 
}
```

now use it

```
for (int i = 0; i < ix; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < iy; j++) {
           progres.setValue(progres.getValue() + 1);
           cells[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, passer);
           gamePanel.add(cells[i][j]);
       }
}
```

now if in constructor of cell you will set a border `this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));` grid will appear. in cell constructor or setter method you can also pass whole cells so each cell will be aware of another, and be able to interact with them. but be aware- if you pass it in loop that also create cells, you might encounter a null values.

this way you can use swing components so each cell can be clickable etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a `JComponent` and overriding its `paint(Graphics)` method to draw the grid using `Graphics.drawLine`.

If you need the grid cells to be interactive in some way, then you should probably just create components with rectangular borders and position them using a grid layout.